# How to filter columns with multiple values for each ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a result set as below and I want to select a single record when the same ID has 2 records with different values for Age and status column, for example

Please see the result set below where ID, name, country name coming from table A and Age, Active status coming from b table

```
ID  name  country Age                  status 
----------------------------------------------
1  Prasad India   NULL                  NULL 
2  John   USA     NULL                  NULL 
3  GREG   AUS     NULL                  NULL 
4  RAVI   India   NULL                  NULL 
4  RAVI   India   18 Years and Above     1
```

Comment: Cant see the result set or any attached image. BTW, folks rather have the data as text than images

Comment: Sorry, I just added text.

Comment: if we table you example how do we choose betwen tthe two records of Ravi india which one to keep?

Comment: 2nd one with the Age and status 1

Comment: What happens if you have age and status at 1?

Comment: When I have 2 records with same ID, I would like to select only 1(with age and status 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with this:

```
    Select * 
    From 
(
    Select t2.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID order by name,country,Age, status desc) as rn
    From yourtable t2
)
Where rn = 1
```